# Series featuring a character named Sheera

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a sci-fi/fantasy series that included a character  named Sheera. It would have been late 60's or early 70's. The world was cold and the concept of hell was an ice covered plain.

Comment: Beasts of Gor has a fleeting reference to a character named Sheera and is set in a frozen wasteland. She appears in other books in the same series; https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/533677.Hunters_of_Gor

Comment: Hunters of Gor is the only reference I can find, though I don't think that mentions a hell/afterlife as an ice covered plain. If it helps jog your memory Sheera is a *panther girl*. These are not werepanthers or some other supernatural being but rather Amazon like women living in the northern forests.

Comment: The Darkover series takes place on a cold world, where their hell is very cold -- I do not think specifically a plain though.  I am pretty sure none of the main characters in the books is named "Sheera", but "Sheera" rings a bell; it could have been a character in one of the many story anthologies.  If so, I have not found it yet; I'll post if I do.

Comment: Just to be clear: When you say it was a "series," do you mean you remember reading a set of full-length novels all set on the same imaginary world? For instance, did you once own, or borrow from a friend or a relative or a library, various paperback novels which were all by the same author and set in this cold place? (As opposed to "it was a series of shorter stories" or "a comic book series" or even "a TV series," for instance.)

Comment: @Basya After I saw you'd mentioned Darkover, I remembered that one of MZB's Darkover novels was titled *Sharra's Exile.* ISFDB says that volume was first published in 1981 -- but of course the series had begun much earlier, and the novel's Wikipedia entry says it was a rewrite of a novel first published in 1962. Seems like a contender, if we assume the OP's memory blurred one of the vowel sounds. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharra%27s_Exile

Comment: @Lorendiac,  Sharra was a weapon, not a person, though.

Comment: @Basya Been so long since I read that book that I don't remember much about it, but the Wikipedia entry for it says, as part of the plot summary: "Ashara explains that Sharra is a goddess and the matrix is a door through which she can reach our world." Other online resources indicate that some of the characters in the story tend to see Sharra as a "daemon." Goddess or demon? Either way, that would let her qualify as a character, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Lorendiac, yes, I guess we could call her a character. Most of the time, "Sharra" refers to a sword though, iirc

Comment: My father named me after this character and I wanted to read the book. He told me it was a series, which means it was multiple books. I don't think he would have misspelled the name as he had the book with him in the hospital. He thinks she had red hair.

Comment: @SheeraEmerson Thank you for clarifying that. I noticed yesterday that you were using the same first name, on here, as the character you were trying to track down, but I didn't realize it was your real name. It makes sense that your father would have had the spelling fresh in his mind when he named you, and would have gotten it right. So I'm giving up on the "might be 'Sharra' from the Darkover series" theory.

Comment: @SheeraEmerson I found a fantasy novel, first of a series, with a woman named Sheera in a prominent role. But it was first published in **1984** -- at least a decade later than the timeframe you suggested. I don't know when you were born. If it was before 1984, then your father couldn't possibly have been inspired by this book.

Comment: The only fantasy novels I've been able to find with a female main character named "Sheera" are *Hunters of Gor* (1974), *The Ladies of Mandrigyn* (1984) - the one Lorendiac is referring to above, and *Knights of Dark Renown* (1989).